# Pricing with log-normal interes rate

Tags: interest-rates, pricing, lognormal

The annual rate of return in year $t$, denoted as $1+i_t$, where $i_0$ represents the interest rate from $t=0$ to $t=1$, has a log-normal distribution with an expected value $108\%$ and a standard deviation $20\%$. Return rates in consecutive years are independent. How much money must be invested at $t=0$ in order to have $95\%$ probability that the investment's value after $5$ years is at least $500$?

My approach:

Let $X$ will be the sought quantity. Then we must find such $X$ that:

$P(X*\prod_{t=0}^{4}(1+i_t) \ge 500)=0.95.$ (*)

We know that $Y:=1+i_t\sim LogN$, where $EY=1.08$ and $VarY=0.04$.

From the properties of the log-normal distribution $lnY\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, where 
$
\begin{cases}
e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}=1.08 \\
(e^{\sigma^2}-1)e^{2\mu+\sigma^2}=0.04
\end{cases}
$

Thus 
$
\begin{cases}
\mu = 0.0601 \\
\sigma^2=0.03371
\end{cases}
$

Now returning to (*):

$P(lnX+5ln(1+i)\ge ln500)=0.95$

$P(ln(1+i)\ge \frac{ln500-lnX}{5})=0.95$

$P(\frac{ln(1+i)-0.0601}{\sqrt{0.03371}}\ge \frac{\frac{ln500-lnX}{5}-0.0601}{\sqrt{0.03371}})=0.95$

$P(N(0,1)\le \frac{\frac{ln500-lnX}{5}-0.0601}{\sqrt{0.03371}})=0.05$

And now from standard normal distribution table:
$\frac{\frac{ln500-lnX}{5}-0.0601}{\sqrt{0.03371}}=-1.64$
$\iff$ $X=1668$, but the asnwer is $X=727$.

Can you see guys where I made a mistake?

Additionally one thing is a little weird for me. Namely, we have to invest at least 727 to have more then 500 with probability 95% after 5 years, so less then we invested at the beginning.